# Переключатель количества без редактирования HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Появилась такая простенькая задачка, но, почему-то не выходит её толком закончить. Необходимо переключатель количества материалов внедрить на страницу, где нет возможности редактировать  html код. Сам выбор значений выглядит так:

```js
(function ($) {
  
  $('.spinner').each(function() {  
    
  var spinner = $(this),
      input = spinner.find('input[type="text"]'),
      btnUp = spinner.find('.up'),
      btnDown = spinner.find('.down'),
      // options
      step = 1,
    min = 1,
    max = 100;
      
  input.val(min);
  
  btnUp.click(function(){
    input.val() >= max ? $(this).prop("disabled",true) : input.val((input.val()*1) + step);
    
 });
  
  btnDown.click(function(){
    input.val() <= min ? $(this).prop("disabled",true) : input.val((input.val()*1) - step);
   });
    
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.spinner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  display: table;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.spinner input[type="text"] {
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: none;
}
.spinner .nav {
  float: left;
}
.spinner .nav .up,
.spinner .nav .down {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.spinner .nav .up:hover,
.spinner .nav .down:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 17px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.spinner .nav .up {
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
.content .container .spinner .nav .down {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spinner">
<input type="text">
<div class="nav">
<div class="up">+</div>
<div class="down">-</div>
</div>
</div>



<div class="spinner"><input name="cnt_10" maxlength="5" size="5" value="1" type="text"></div>
<div class="spinner"><input name="cnt_11" maxlength="5" size="5" value="1" type="text"></div>
```

Там же есть и пример кода с инпутами, к которым необходимо добавить кнопки + и - . Пробовал через .append создать структуру перед выполнением функции внутри блока с инпутами, но переключатель перестает работать. Если нужно, добавлю свой код, но, учитывая, что он не работает, толку от этого не много. Буду благодарен за пример или хотя бы направление мысли.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот [готовое решение](http://codepen.io/bitblitter/pen/sjApv) для ваших нужд:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){    
    inputNumberPolyfill();  
});

var increaseIv = null;
var increaseTm = null;

function inputNumberPolyfill()
{
  //if(Modernizr.inputtypes.number) return;  
  $('.spinner input[type="text"]').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);    
    var step = parseInt($this.attr('step'), 10);
    if(isNaN(step)) step = 1;
    
    $this.parent().append(
      '<div class="nav">'+
      '<a class="up" data-value="'+step+'" href="#">'+
      '<span class="label">+</span>'+
      '</a>'+
      '<a class="down" data-value="-'+step+'" href="#">'+
      '<span class="label">-</span>'+
      '</a>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>');
  });
  
  $('.nav a').mousedown(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault(); 
    clearInterval(increaseIv);
    clearTimeout(increaseTm);
    var input = $(this);
    increaseInput(input);    
    increaseTm = setTimeout(function(){
      increaseIv = setInterval(function(){
        increaseInput(input);
      }, 60);
    }, 300);
    return false;
  }).mouseup(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    clearTimeout(increaseTm);
    clearInterval(increaseIv);
    return false;
  }).mouseout(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    clearTimeout(increaseTm);
    clearInterval(increaseIv);
    return false;
  });
  
  
  
  $('.spinner input[type="text"]').change(function(ev){
    var $this = $(this);
    var minValue = parseInt($this.attr('min'));
    var maxValue = parseInt($this.attr('max'));
    if(isNaN(minValue)) minValue = 0;
    if(isNaN(maxValue)) maxValue = 9999999;
    var inputValue = parseInt($this.val());
    if(isNaN(inputValue)) inputValue = 0;
    
    var finalValue = Math.min(maxValue, Math.max(minValue, inputValue));
    if(finalValue != inputValue)
      $this.val(finalValue);
  });
}

function increaseInput(input)
{
  var $this = input;
    var spinner = $this.parent();    
    var spinnerValue = parseInt($this.attr('data-value'), 10);
    var target = spinner.parent().find('input[type="text"]');  
  
    var targetValue = parseInt(target.val(), 10);
    if(isNaN(targetValue))
      targetValue = 0;    
    var minVal = parseInt(target.attr('min'));
    var maxVal = parseInt(target.attr('max'));
    
    if(isNaN(minVal)) minVal = 0;
    if(isNaN(maxVal)) maxVal = 9999999;
    
    var finalValue = targetValue + spinnerValue;
    finalValue = Math.min(maxVal, Math.max(minVal, finalValue));    
    target.val(finalValue);    
}
```

```css
.spinner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  display: table;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.spinner input[type="text"] {
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: none;
}
.spinner .nav {
  float: left;
}
.spinner .nav .up,
.spinner .nav .down {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.spinner .nav .up:hover,
.spinner .nav .down:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 17px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.spinner .nav .up {
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
.content .container .spinner .nav .down {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spinner"><input name="cnt_10" maxlength="5" size="5" value="1" type="text"></div>
<div class="spinner"><input name="cnt_11" maxlength="5" size="5" value="1" type="text"></div>
```

Comment: О, вот это то, что было нужно. Спасибо)

Answer (score 3):

```js
(function ($) {

    var step = 1,
        min = 1,
        max = 10;

    $('.spinner').each(function(i, el) {
        var $spinner = $(el),
            $nav = $spinner.find('.nav');
        if(!$nav.length) {
            $spinner.append('<div class="nav"> <div class="up">+</div> <div class="down">-</div> </div>');
        }
    });

    $('input').val(min);
    $(document).on('click', '.up', function (e) {
        var $this = $(e.target),
            $spinner = $this.closest('.spinner'),
            $input = $spinner.find('input'),
            val = $input.val();
        if(val < max) {
            $input.val((val * 1) + step);
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.down',function (e) {
        var $this = $(e.target),
            $spinner = $this.closest('.spinner'),
            $input = $spinner.find('input'),
            val = $input.val();
        if(val > min) {
            $input.val((val * 1) - step);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.spinner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  display: table;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.spinner input[type="text"] {
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: none;
}
.spinner .nav {
  float: left;
}
.spinner .nav .up,
.spinner .nav .down {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.spinner .nav .up:hover,
.spinner .nav .down:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 17px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.spinner .nav .up {
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
.content .container .spinner .nav .down {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spinner">
<input type="text">
<div class="nav">
<div class="up">+</div>
<div class="down">-</div>
</div>
</div>



<div class="spinner"><input name="cnt_10" maxlength="5" size="5" value="1" type="text"></div>
<div class="spinner"><input name="cnt_11" maxlength="5" size="5" value="1" type="text"></div>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Суть вопроса была в том, что необходимо создать `div.nav` с кнопками внутри `.spinner`, после чего выполнить функцию изменения количества. То есть, отредактировать код нет возможности.

Comment: @Alexander Goroshev, обновил код

Comment: Спасибо. А почему в HTML коде до сих пор разметка? Ага вижу, то есть, если .nav отсутствует, то он создается. Правильно?